# invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors

I am trying to replace a certain character in a string with a space using the following code line:

```
str[i] = " ";
```

How can realize this without getting the error in the title of the question?

Comment: I'll assume C++, since you didn't say.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use single quotes

```
str[ i ] = ' ';
```

In C++, the token `" "` is a string literal which represents an array of two characters: the value of a space in the character set (eg, the value 32 in ascii) and a zero.  On the other hand, the token `' '` represents a single character with the value of a space (usually 32).  Note that in C, the token `' '` represents an integer with the value of a space.  (In C, `sizeof ' ' == sizeof(int)`, while in C++, `sizeof ' ' == sizeof(char) == 1`.)

Answer (score 5):

Single `char` literals are obtained with *single* quotes:

```
str[i] = ' ';
```

A literal with double-quotes is a full string literal (a null-terminated array of `char`), but you're only replacing a single `char`.